# include inside a variable - includes without print the variable

Tags: php, include

This is odd... I want to include a file inside a variable to print it later but it's already including the file without printing the variable...

```
$var = include('file.php');
// stuff
echo $var;
```

file.php:

```
echo $stuff;
```

Output:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: stuff in file.php
```

I commented the `echo $var` to make sure but it's included anyways...

Is there any way to just load the content inside the variable instead of including the file?

Comment: do you mean by loading the content that you're expecting to see "echo $stuff"; as $var? If so, you want `file_get_contents('file.php')`

However, if you want it to actually replace the value, then you want file.php to have `return $stuff`

Comment: If the file content is loaded before `stuff` will take the variable when printed after it?

Comment: I don't understand your above comment.
If you have `echo $stuff;` in file.php, it's the same as having a function where it echos the value instead of returning it. You need `return $stuff` instead, if you want $var to get the same value as $stuff. If you want the entire file, code and all, as a string though, then take Scais' solution.

Comment: Yes, I'll use `file_get_contents()`. I just wanted to make sure that when I print the content, the variables inside it will be the ones above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try  file_get_contents

```
<?php
  $var  = file_get_contents('file.php');
 echo $var;
 ?>
```

Comment: So the answer would be: `include()` will always include the file even if it's called inside a variable. Thanks, I'll accept the answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: include() is for loading part of php code. in $var you set the result of the operation not the file

Comment: But it's normal that by just doing `$var = include('file.php');` includes it? (without printing `$var`)

Comment: try this `if (include('vars.php') == 'OK') {
    echo 'OK';
}`

Comment: In the way you do you set in $var the boolean of the result of the include action

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like you did

```
$var = include 'file.php';
```

The included file needs to return a value, though.
Last in file.php:

```
// Do some stuff (but don't echo anything)
return 'This will be put in the var-variable to be echoed or used when you see fit';
```